# Маркер или маркёр?

Tags: фонетика

А как, собственно, правильно называть фломастер для выделения текста: мАркер (как все говорят) или маркЁр?
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Существуют два разных слова: мАркер и маркЁр.

МАРКЕР, -а; м. [от англ. to mark - отмечать, обозначать].Фломастер с широким пористым стержнем, пропитанным красящей жидкостью для выделения цветом частей текста, надписей на упаковке и т.п

МАРКЁР, -а; м. [франц. marqueur,от marquer — отмечать)
 Лицо, прислуживающее при игре на бильярде и ведущее счёт очков (во время игры). Служить маркёром.

МАРКЁР,  С.-х. Приспособление к посевному агрегату для проведения на земле посадочных или посевных бороздок.

Comment: А еще есть слово "онкомаркер".
Онкомаркеры — специфические вещества,продукты жизнедеятельности опухоли или вещества, продуцируемые нормальными тканями в ответ на инвазию раковых клеток, которые обнаруживаются в крови и/или моче больных раком. Врачи произносят это слово с буквой Ё.

Comment: И ЕЩЁ - "МАРКЁР" - это метка, признак (например, в психологии или биологии).