# Широта значений понятия "маркёр"

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

Можно ли употреблять слово "маркёр" в значении "метка", "помета"? Надпись ручкой на книге, в нотах, граффити на стене и просто какой-либо знак. Например, особая манера высказывания мысли может быть маркёром определённого стиля, свеча на столе — маркёром романтического ужина. Может ли употребляться слово в значении "атрибут"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33364/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%91%D1%80

Comment: В том, что вы скинули, приводятся омографы (различие значений слов в зависимости от ударений). Меня же интересует только слово маркёр, как можно более подробное описание его возможностей употребления, главным образом в значении "метка" среди всего многообразия значений.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, у слова "маркёр" такого смыслового значения нет даже близко. Слово "маркер" (с ударением на первом слоге) имеет некоторые схожие значения в узкоспециальных областях, но именно как физически присутствующий значок, отмечающий какую-то позицию.

Использовать это слово в общем смысле в значении "знак, метка" будет всё-таки неправильно.

Ссылки:
[маркёр](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/855898), [маркёр](https://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%91%D1%80), [маркёр](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%91%D1%80)

Насчет "маркера" словари выражаются менее определённо, но можно сослаться, например на [викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80) или даже, прости господи, на [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80).